# By induction define a sequence $I=I_0 \supseteq I_1 \supseteq \ldots$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Could you explain hint part, I don't understand what it means.

Let $\alpha: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given. For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ show that there is a point $c$ in the closed interval $I=[a,b]$ such that $c \notin \{\alpha(n) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Conclude from this that $I$, and hence $\mathbb{R}$ also, are uncountable. (Hint: By induction define a sequence $I=I_0 \supseteq I_1 \supseteq \ldots$ of closed intervals such that $\alpha(n) \notin I_{n+1}$ and use the fact that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}I_n \neq \emptyset$.)

Comment: What is the problem? Do you not see how to build a closed $I_1$ such tat $\alpha(0) \notin I_1$? Do you understand why the intersection of all the $I_n$ would be non-empty? Do you not see how the conclusion follows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: given any interval $[c,d]$ with $c<d$ and any finite set $F$ of real numbers you can find an interval $[x,y]$ contained in $[c,d]$ such that $x<y$ and this interval does not contain any of the points of the finite set $F$. Now use induction. Take $I_0=I_1=I$ and pick a closed interval $I_2 \subset I_1$ such that $\alpha (1) \notin I_2$. Then pick a closed interval $I_3 \subset I_2$ such that $\alpha (1) \notin I_3$ and $\alpha (2) \notin I_3$, and so on.

I hope the rest of the argument is clear to you.

Comment: Why can you choose $I_1=I$?

Comment: @Bernard The first requirement is $\alpha (1) \notin I_2$ and their is no requirement on $I_1$. So we are free to take it is $I$.

Comment: For me, the first requirement is $\alpha(0)\notin I_1$. $\mathbf N$ starts at $0$.

Comment: It is customary to use $\mathbb N$ for the set of positive integers. But if you want to include $0$ my argument works with a  very trivial modification. In the definition of a countable set  also one normally uses positive intgers

Comment: Sure, but Peano's axioms as well as Bourbaki include $0$. It would be a mess, for instance, to define polynomials without it!